# How to run a Javascript function on an iframe before the source (src) is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, iframe

I've asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718093/how-to-force-no-scrollbars-on-iframe-in-html5) question before this one, trying to figure out why I was seeing scrollbars on the [a-ads](https://a-ads.com) iframes, on [this](http://old.payspigot.com/) website, while some swear they didn't see them!
Hence, I have discovered that the appearance of the iFrame scrollbars is by execution order. And with faster or slower computers, results may vary.

I realize that I have to replace `scrolling="no"`, a strong (but unsupported in HTML5), attribute that forces no scrollbars on iframes, with a JavaScript, or CSS alternative. However, the CSS `overflow:hidden;` is too weak to override whatever style the iframe's source may contain (e.g. `overflow:scroll`, `overflow:auto`, etc.). So the solution must be with JavaScript.

The caveat however, is that the javascript must activate *after* the iframe itself is loaded, but *before* the source (`src=""`) is loaded. Because if `scrolling="no"` is replaced *after* the source is loaded it has no effect on the outcome of the iframe display. Though, if it is place *before* the `<iframe>` tag markup is reached, how does the JavaScript know what to modify? It is as good as not present at that point.

One More Problem: The source can't be stripped from the `<iframe>` tag, and replaced in JavaScript. We've tried that, and while it worked....sort of... we lost ad impressions and clicks into a black hole, because the spider (i.e. bot) at [a-ads](https://a-ads.com) couldn't, or had problems with, detecting the proper a-ads code on the webpage. But if we left it in the iframe and just reloaded the source after `scrolling="no"` was set, then that would result in double ad-loads (i.e. invalid impressions).

This is a real pickle!

All the Einsteins of the world - You're Needed!

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742344/run-script-before-iframe-loads) S.O. question doesn't apply.

#### Screenshots

[Chrome Proof](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69455950/screenshots/stack-overflow/resilient_scrollbars_issue/chrome-scrollbars-proof.png)

[IE Proof](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69455950/screenshots/stack-overflow/resilient_scrollbars_issue/ie-scrollbars-proof.png)

[Opera Proof](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69455950/screenshots/stack-overflow/resilient_scrollbars_issue/opera_screenshot_proof.png)

[Firefox was best-behaved](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69455950/screenshots/stack-overflow/resilient_scrollbars_issue/firefox_looks_normal.png)

Comment: Do you have the ability to add css/js inside the iframe? Is the iframe src coming from the same domain?

Comment: Hi, @Jackson , No the source is coming from an off-site ad server at a-ads.com. Thanks for asking! :-)

Comment: Is this iframe created by script? If not why can't the html source be modified? If it is script created would need interval timer to detect it's existence

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, Any script, or markup on  [our domain](http://old.payspigot.com) can be manipulated, or modified, except *only* by the conditions outlined above. However the page/markup/script of the `src` of the iframes (i.e. the child frames), is beyond our control to modify. Thanks for asking ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has now been solved, for now, I think. Here is the solution:

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function noScrollBarsOnAAdUnit( ElementID )
    {   

        document.getElementById( ElementID ).setAttribute("scrolling", "no");       
        return true;

    };

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">noScrollBarsOnAAdUnit( 'aa-unit-top-center' );</script>
    <iframe id='aa-unit-top-center' style='width:468px;height:60px;' class='a-ads-frame' data-aa='[ad-id]' src='https://ad.a-ads.com/[ad-id]?size=468x60'>
        <!-- iframe fallback message here -->
    </iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">noScrollBarsOnAAdUnit( 'aa-unit-top-center' );</script>

</body>
```

Fellow S.O. members, please, check [this](http://old.payspigot.com) page, to assure this fix is consistent, and really works at least 99.99%, if not 100%, of the time.

Thanks!

-James A.